# How to resize div based on text within div

Tags: html, css, less

I have different `div`'s which looks like this:

```
<div class="marker marker-availability" style="left: 975.516px; top: 346.265px;">
    <span class="marker-label">Tenten comfort</span>
    <div style="background-color:#7ba1bc" class="cluster-background">
        <span class="marker-id">81</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="marker marker-availability">
  <span class="marker-label">Standaard kampeerplaatsen</span>
  <div style="background-color:#d99200" class="cluster-background">
     <span class="marker-id">81</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

But now I have an issue because I set an `:after` with an image to the bottom of the image which looks like this:

[image]

Now you see the issue very clear, I tried to set the `height` to auto and set an `min-height` but this will not solve the problem.

I have recreated a jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swgby66a/)

Here is my less code:

```css
&.marker-availability {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 23px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6f6926;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-left: -60px;
  margin-top: -26px;

  .marker-label {
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .cluster-background {
    .square(25px);
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: -12px;
    border-radius: 50%;


    &:after {
      .retina-image('/img/map/clustermarker-point.png', '/img/map/clustermarker-pointx2.png', 184px, 55px);
      .pos-b-l(-26px, 50%);
      .translate(-50%, -50%);
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 120px;
      height: 20px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
  }

  .marker-id {
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-left: 1px;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

Thereby, my question is it possible to make it look like this:

[image]

Or is it not possible because of the position of the :after image

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/swgby66a/3/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was primarily your negative margins which should be avoided if possible.

I've updated your example, you just need to adjust the paddings:

https://jsfiddle.net/txsv0ha5/

removed:

```
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: -12px;
```

Also your bottom background shouldn't be an :after Element of your colored circles but rather of the whole marker itself.

Comment: It was the negatives only?

Comment: There were several problems but your negative margins prevented the box from growing in height, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You have some trouble with your css.

[image]

1. The main problem is the negative `margin`. If you do so, all the height of the parent is reduce. So, you need to add `position:absolute`.
2. Change the `:after` element to the parent so it will relative to the parent and not connected to the `cluster-background`.

```css
.marker-availability {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  min-height: 23px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6f6926;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-top: 26px;
  position:absolute;
}
.marker-availability .marker-label {
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
}
.marker-availability .cluster-background {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position:absolute;
}
.marker-availability:after {
  background: url('http://i65.tinypic.com/bhytdd.png');
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -26px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.marker-availability .marker-id {
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color: black">

  <div class="marker marker-availability" style="left: 975.516px; top: 346.265px;"><span class="marker-label">Tenten comfort</span><div style="background-color:#7ba1bc" class="cluster-background"><span class="marker-id">81</span></div></div>

  <div class="marker marker-availability"><span class="marker-label">Standaard kampeerplaatsen</span><div style="background-color:#d99200" class="cluster-background"><span class="marker-id">81</span></div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/swgby66a/2/ as you see the marker-availability is not positioned right

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what do you mean. Can you take a picture for the expected result?